# Communicate between 2 processes using named pipes in perl?

Tags: perl, named-pipes

I'm trying to solve this problem using named pipes:

I have one process that runs continuously. This process should just check the named pipe if there is any data available there. If not, I have replacement data (cached data) to use for this situation.

It's very important, that this one continuously running process, does not block, and if there's no process attached at the "other end" of the named pipe, this continuously running process should resort to cached data.

Then I have a second process. This process can be started at-will, but will normally be run from a cron script at regular intervals. This process, will dump data into the named pipe.

Ideally, I would want this data to be just dumped into the named pipe, waiting for it to be available for the continuously running process to pick up at any time. The continuously process could hold its pipe open at all times if possible, or it could open the pipe when it needs data.

But if its required, this intermittialy running process could hold its pipe open until data is processed by the continiously running process.

Any good ideas to accomplish this? I suspect I could somehow open a pipe, even if theres no process on the other end without blocking, but of course there would be no data until a process attaches on other end of the named pipe and sends data.

And when this process detaches, will buffered data still be available for the reading application, even if the read is made after the detachment?

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure that you need to go to that trouble for the described purpose.  Why not dump information into a plain file, which the ever-running process can check for and read?  Or, use a socket which is far more flexible? But what you ask can be done of course.

The writer gets blocked at opening the FIFO until the reader opens it, what is OK from what I read in the question. The reader can check in a non-blocking way by using a `select`. But then it's simpler that the writer creates the pipe in the first place and deletes it once it's done, so the reader knows that there is no new data when there's no file to open,.

**Writer**

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';

my $fifo = 'test.fifo';

if (-e $fifo) { unlink $fifo  or die "Can't unlink $fifo: $!" }

system('mkfifo', $fifo) and system('mknod', $fifo, 'p') 
    and die "Can't make $fifo: $!";

open my $fh, '>', $fifo or die "Can't open fifo $fifo: $!";  # Blocks here until
say $fh "Message to fifo from $$";                           # there's a reader
close $fh;

unlink $fifo or die "Error unlinking $fifo: $!";
```

**Reader**, the ever-running program

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';

use Errno qw(ENOENT);

my $fifo = 'test.fifo';

while (1) { 
    say "\nDo work (sleep a little really), try for message ...";
    sleep 3;

    if (my $msg = read_fifo($fifo)) { 
        say $msg;
        #last;     # done with this exercise
    }

    # Run the writer program in another terminal at some point
    # Or, to simulate that:
    #my $pid = fork // die "Can't fork: $!";
    #if ($pid == 0) { exec $writer_path }
}
    
sub read_fifo {
    my ($fifo) = @_;
    open my $fh, '<', $fifo  or do {
        if ($! == ENOENT) {
            say "No file $fifo -- no new data, carry on and use default";
            return;
        }
        else { die "Can't open fifo $fifo: $!" }  # some other error
    };
    return join '', <$fh>;
}
```

This leaves out more testing that would be appropriate, and yet other details.

In my take all this shows firstly that communicating over a plain file is far simpler in this case.

---

The problem got rounded with a lot of context, provided in comments and a chat. One detail substantially changes the problem: the writer actually *can't wait*. Here is a way to handle that.

The writer needs to do other things after making data available, picked up by the reader at an unspecified time, so it cannot wait at the pipe. Then `fork` a process in the writer and deal with the FIFO in that child process, while the parent is free to do what it needs.

Writer from above, now handling FIFO in a child process

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';

my $fifo = 'test.fifo';

my $pid = fork // die "Can't fork: $!";

if ($pid == 0) {  
    if (-e $fifo) { unlink $fifo  or die "Can't unlink $fifo: $!" }

    system('mkfifo', $fifo) and system('mknod', $fifo, 'p') 
        and die "Can't make $fifo: $!";

    open my $fh, '>', $fifo or die "Can't open fifo $fifo: $!"; # awaits reader
    say $fh "Message to fifo from $$";
    close $fh;
    
    unlink $fifo or die "Error unlinking $fifo: $!";

    exit;
}

# parent can now do its work

# Always reap -- but now also must not leave until FIFO's been read
my $gone = waitpid $pid, 0;
if ($gone > 0) { say "FIFO-handling child exited with $?" }
```

This can be tested the same way as the initial writer, with the same reader.

The writer's child is waiting on the pipe in a blocked `open`, until the reader gets to go to read it. As the reader opens the pipe for reading the writer's `open` completes and the data gets written, and is received by the reader.  Or there is no FIFO at all and the reader's `open` fails (with `ENOENT`) so the reader knows that there is no new data and can use its default.

Comment: aah, the writer cannot block either, as its the writer that later on causes it to be read. But as the reader can have the file open permanently, it shouldn't be a concern. But deleting the file wouldn't work in this case.

Comment: @sebastiannielsen What's said in the question and now here adds up to impossible. Named pipes block.  They do _look like_ regular files but there's really a program meant to be on the other end, so if there is in fact no program it has to block.  By what you say here you really want a plain file, like I suggest both in the opening and closing of the answer. (What's wrong with that?)

Comment: @sebastiannielsen  Re: "_its the writer that later on causes it to be read_"  --- heh?  So the writer dumps info ... but only later (somehow) makes it be read...?  That doesn't make sense really.  Perhaps you could explain the whole design a little?  At this point I suspect that you may _not_ want a named pipe at all.

Comment: The thing is that disk IO is slow. So what I have, is a short-running process, which creates data X, and then dumps it to second process. The short-running process then tells a third-party to verify data X, which it does by then talking to a server which is attached to the long-running process. BUT there is a catch: The third party reads data X for several times, like 30-40 times, from different locations. I have to read from disk to be sure if there is new data or not, regardless of if I have the data cached or not.

Comment: So im interested in the select() solution. So the long-running process can check if the fifo pipe is available (ergo the short-running process is alive). If it is, I want to read whatever the short-running process dumped, and cache that. Subsuquent reads, I can know I already "fetched" the data because the fifo pipe is empty for the moment, and thus fallback to cached data.

In a file-based scenario, this could be compared with deleting the file after read, but checking for file existense still needs disk IO, but checking for a empty FIFO pipe just needs some digging in RAM.

Comment: im not sure it really HAS to block, or in other words, it must be a way to attach to a named pipe in such a way to tell "If it would block while reading, then continue without blocking, and use cached data instead".
I also readed in a other source that you could open the reader end in read/write mode to avoid having the pipe block at open, it will instead block at read if theres no process available on the other end - and this must be possible to test for? And thus use cached data. (while the writer process can attach at any time and dump its data - and then continue on)

Comment: @sebastiannielsen Wow, alright, that's plenty, thank you!  It's past one o'clock in the morning here so I need to go but I will look into the whole problem tomorrow.  A couple of quick comments follow..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214093/discussion-between-sebastian-nielsen-and-zdim).

Comment: @sebastiannielsen Added a version of the writer where it handles the FIFO  in a child process.  Then the parent can go do what's needed while the child is waiting for the reader to open the FIFO.  The long-running reader doesn't need to wait for anything -- it can open FIFO as it pleases, at which point the child's open completes (and then data is wrtten). Or, the reader's open fails if there is no file so it knows to use default.  I'll look more at what you explained in the chat, but this is a legitimate option as well.

Comment: @sebastiannielsen  By now I've reviewed this repeatedly, our chat in particular (just completed another careful read-over), and at this point I don't know what else could be reasonably more sensible or better than what's posted above; thus I'd consider the above a "complete" answer to the question as asked and clarified. (Clearly, the full problem is more complex than any one "answer" but that's the Real World, not Stackoverflow :).  Another option being to simply use files or flags, but that's not what was asked.